# Adding Images and Text in Element Ui Carousel in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

Please I'm still new using VueJs and am working on a new project and I'm having issues adding images and text in Element UI Carousel for Vue, please how do I add images and text in the Carousel?

```
  <el-carousel :interval="4000" type="card" height="400px">
    <el-carousel-item v-for="item in 6" :key="item">
      <h3 class="medium">{{ item }}</h3>
    </el-carousel-item>
  </el-carousel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the link to  CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-sky-o82gq?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Can you maybe provide a code sandbox with the example? 

Comment: Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-haze-nf96j?file=/src/components/Carousel.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put content in the slides, by repeating the `<el-carousel-item>` and putting text/images inside it.

You can simply put content in like this:

```
<el-carousel :interval="4000" type="card" height="300px">
    <el-carousel-item>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item__content">
          Text for slide 1
        </div>
        <img class="item__image" src="https://picsum.photos/300?random=1" alt="" />
      </div>
    </el-carousel-item>
    <el-carousel-item>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item__content">
          Another text for slide 2
        </div>
        <img class="item__image" src="https://picsum.photos/300?random=2" alt="" />
      </div>
    </el-carousel-item>
    <el-carousel-item>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item__content">
          Yet another for third image
        </div>
        <img class="item__image" src="https://picsum.photos/300?random=3" alt="" />
      </div>
    </el-carousel-item>
  </el-carousel>
```

I have created an example where i add different images and some text to the carousel:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hill-osoxh?file=/src/components/Carousel.vue

Does this answer your question?

Comment: My code is similar to yours but I have also some buttons in cards inside `el-carousel-item`. Do you know how can we adjust width of  `el-carousel-item`? Because it's width seems too much for the card that I am placing in carousel item.